# Site Policy/Closure Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, expiration, information-policy

I’ve run into a site policy issue that I wondered if anyone could help validate, or have a solution for. In this scenario we’ve tried local site policies, as well as policies published via a content type hub. Both perform the same.

A site policy was created to close the site x days after creation, and delete x days after closure. The checkbox was checked to state that the site should be read only when closed.

When manually closing the site through the “Close Site” button on the Site Closure and Deletion screen, the site is successfully closed, and the red banner is shown that the site is read only.

When leveraging the timer job to close the site automatically, per the policy, the site is closed, but the read only specification is ignored.

I’m assuming this is a bug in the Expiration Policy timer job, as it appears to be ignoring the setting to mark as read only. We’ve validated this in multiple environments and they all behave exactly the same way.

I’ve confirmed this behavior in multiple farms with the following versions:

15.0.4481.1005 (March 2013 PU)
15.0.4505.1005 (April 2013 PU)

Comment: Are these sites or sub-sites? ........................

Comment: Behavior is the same on both.